# How to make GUI.Box corners rounded in Unity programmatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know much about C# and Unity. I just follow the script in [Vuforia's Unity Cloud Recognition tutorial](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/How-To-Implement-Cloud-Reco.html#unity), which creates the GUI Box programmatically. So I guess all the stying solutions using the Unity `Inspector` are not working for me.

**My current GUI.Box style**

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
texture.SetPixel(0,0,Color.white);
texture.Apply();

GUIStyle myBoxStyle2 = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.box);
myBoxStyle2.fontSize = 40;
myBoxStyle2.normal.background = texture;
myBoxStyle2.normal.textColor = Color.black;
myBoxStyle2.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleLeft;
GUI.Box (new Rect(Screen.width/4,Screen.height/6,Screen.width/2,Screen.height/8), mTargetMetadata, myBoxStyle2);
```

And it looks like this (the white box)

[image]

I checked the [GUI Style Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/class-GUIStyle.html), not helped.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the rounded corners from the the image background used. As you're using a pure white texture, with hard corners, your corners are going to be hard.

Comment: @Draco18s so I should change the texture or? I just want a white background and rounded corner, I don't have to use the Texture2D, using any other methods would be fine.

Comment: You could use the built-in texture called `UISprite` which has rounded corners (usually used for Button) or [buy something from the AssetStore](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/procedural-ui-image-52200). Anyway did you try to simply not create a new style for it? Afaik by default it uses a rounded texture anyway? And finally: Are you bound to use `GUI.Box`? Why not simply use the [UI System](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui) introduced in Unity 4?

Comment: @derHugo because the default one has a gray background which makes the text a little bit unclear. Thx, I'll try the `Sprite` one.

Answer (score 1):

The rounded corners are actually the default style for [`GUI.Box`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Box.html).

Internally afaik by default it simply uses the `UISprite` as texture. In order to use it as well on your `MonoBehaviour` component you could have a

```
public Texture2D boxTexture;
```

and reference the UISprite in it in order to use it for your style.

---

However it sounds like actually your question seems to be rather

**How to change the color of GUI.Box?**

So using `GUI` you could directly change the color using

```
// store current values before changing
var color = GUI.color;
var contentColor = GUI.contentColor;

// change GUI colors
GUI.color = Color.white;
GUI.contentColor = Color.black;
{
    // draw Box with default style
    GUI.Box (new Rect(Screen.width/4,Screen.height/6,Screen.width/2,Screen.height/8), mTargetMetadata);
}
// reset GUI colors to former stored values
GUI.color = color;
GUI.contentColor = contentColor;
```

either this should already fix it or you could try doing the same but using [`GUI.backgroundColor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-backgroundColor.html) instead of [`GUI.color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-color.html). And just to make the list complete: The text color you can change doing the same thing with [`GUI.contentColor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-contentColor.html).

---

However in general ... I would say Vuforia gave you a very bad option there. Using `GUI` **was** actually the way to go way back until Unity 4.5. (so more or less 2015).

It is still in use but actually alsmost *only* for [Building Custom Inspectors](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector) and other editor scripting.

Nowadays as mentioned in the comments you should rather use the ["New" UI System](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui) introduced in Unity 4.6.